# Emoji does not display in the push notification

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, push, emoji

I have the push notification, which have in body '\u270c' what is emoji. But when I receive notification it shows this code '\u270c, not emoji. How to resolve this?

Comment: try this for objective c : NSString *emoji = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 0x270c];

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you?

```
let unicodeReceived = "\\u270c"
if let integer = Int(unicodeReceived.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\u", with: ""), radix: 16),
    let scalar = UnicodeScalar(integer) {
    let value = String(scalar)
    print(value)
}
```